# Error while trying to load gem 'coffee-rails'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am getting this error while running ***rake db:create***

> Error while trying to load gem 'coffee-rails'

I have updated nodejs.

Comment: I am getting this error?

Comment: @fool-dev think OP meant the error in title

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you've installed NodeJS.

You can try removing the Gemfile.lock file, then changing the version of therubyracer in Gemfile to 0.12.3, then do bundle install.